# PHP DNS resolver

Tags: php, dns

I need to resolve dns.
Here is my cmd command:

```
host -a google.com 8.8.8.8
```

or

```
(host -a s4.artemisweb.jp ns0.domain_name.com
 host -a s4.artemisweb.jp 77.88.8.1)
```

and it returns something like that:

```
root@min /etc # host -a google.com 8.8.8.8
Trying "google.com"
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Trying "google.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6364
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 24, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       74.125.232.103
google.com.             300     IN      A       74.125.232.96
google.com.             300     IN      A       74.125.232.102
google.com.             300     IN      A       74.125.232.97
```

for my further work i need

```
74.125.232.103            74.125.232.96 etc. ip addresses.(answer section)
```

Actually php has

```
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);
```

but I also have second parameter

```
"8.8.8.8" or "ns0.domain_name.com or 77.88.8.1"
```

(and with this additional parameters "host" command returns different IP) and there is no place for it in command above.

Answer (score 0):

Use nslookup instead simplier output and each ip has Address: at the front so easy to regex

```
[root@sid ~]# nslookup www.google.com
Server:         10.0.0.253
Address:        10.0.0.253#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.99
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.147
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.104
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.103
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.106
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.24.105
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
$resolver = new Net_DNS_Resolver();
$resolver->debug = 1; // Turn on debugging output to show the query
$resolver->usevc = 1; // Force the use of TCP instead of UDP
$resolver->nameservers = array(              // Set the IP addresses
                           '198.41.0.4',     // of the nameservers
                           '192.228.79.201'  // to query.
                           );
   $response = $resolver->query('example.com');
   if (! $response) {
      echo "\n";
      echo "ANCOUNT is 0, therefore the query() 'failed'\n";
      echo "See Net_DNS_Resolver::rawQuery() to receive this packet\n";
   }
?>
```